Steam Web API Access is denied
I'm trying to get steam inventory, but getting error "Forbidden Access is denied. Retrying will not help. Please verify your key= parameter."
The key is parameter is right its working for others reqs.Its not working only for this one
https://partner.steam-api.com/IInventoryService/GetInventory/v1/?key=<key>&appid=730&steamid=<id>

Maybe this method is deprecated or something?Official docs did not helped me :(

the error says your key is wrong ... not that the method is invalid ... there's something wrong with your key

May be your key doesn't have access to that specific resource.

The creator of SteamDB, xPaw, also created a website for Steam Web API documentation and (minimal) testing. Steam is historically bad about some documentation & updates when there's changes, so it's always worth looking for third-party docs.

I got the same error and decided to use steam web inventory API. Take a look at https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/{STEAMID_64}/730/2?count=2000
You can get STEAMID_64 by any login from this API: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key={STEAM_API_KEY}&vanityurl={login}

You need a publisher API key to access any web api, not just the one generated at steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey.
Try here:
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/auth

You don't need a publisher API to access any web API. There are APIs that require only one API key. In fact, you're linking to a documentation page that states that some APIs need the publisher key.
